# JPQL performance analysis

Tags: mysql, performance, jpa

I am trying to take a look into our database performance issues by making a common **EXPLAIN select (...)** in our mysql database, however our software (written in JAVA) is using JPQL. My point is, all queries are using objects and I wanted to reproduce the mysql query exactly as the one produced by the JPA (can this be done? I mean, it will have to be converted to sql at some point).

Could anyone explain how can I translate this (JPQL) into a sql query? Or even, point me if there is any way I can do the **EXPLAIN** directly in JPA so I can make some UTs for this task.

I know there is a way to show the queries directly in console while running the UTs, perhaps I could try finding out how to set it, but I am not sure if it displays the native query instead of an JPQL query.

Just to make clear my goal here:

- Use **EXPLAIN** or something similar
  to point out performance issues in or
  database.
- Technologies involved: JPA and MySql.

Some solutions I thought about (which I'd like you guys to point out if they are feasible):

- Find out how the JPQL is converted to
  SQL and use the old **EXPLAIN**
  method.
- Find out how to use **EXPLAIN** directly in JPA
- Trace MySql logs or console (when running my UTs) :(

Thx,
Flavio.

Comment: Which JPA implementation are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging is not standardized for JPA, so enabling logging is dependent on your JPA provider,

for EclipseLink use the persistence.xml property,

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: This should do it, tracking the logs will give me the queries I need!!
Thx @James. 
But still I will leave this open to see if anyone has an answer for using EXPLAIN directly in JPQL.